# Powershell-командлеты, нигде не описанные в проекте на GitHub, но использующиеся при сборке

Tags: github, powershell, nuget

Есть на github.com проект Nuget Gallery, среди файлов которого присутствует PowerShell-скрипт [build.ps1](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/blob/master/build.ps1)

В коде этого скрипта используются неведомые (в том числе и гуглу) командлеты:
***Trace-Log***, ***Invoke-BuildStep***, ***Install-PrivateBuildTools***, ***Install-NuGet***, ***Clear-PackageCache*** и т.д.

Собстенно, вопрос: откуда их брать?

В инструкции по сборке про них ни слова. Просто написано:

> 1.Prerequisites:
>
> ```
>  i.Visual Studio 2017 - Install the following  Workloads : 
>
>   ◾ASP.NET and web development 
>
>   ◾Azure development
>
>  ii.PowerShell 4.0
> ```
>
> 2.Clone it!
>
> ```
>  PS C:\Code> git clone https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery.git
> ```
>
> 3.Build it!
>
> ```
>  PS C:\Code> cd NuGetGallery 
>  PS C:\Code\NuGetGallery> .\build
> ```

Разумеется, выполнение п.1 требований никак не повлияло на появление необходимых коммандлетов.

Answer (score 0):

Эти командлеты лежат в репозитории ServerCommon и скачиваются вот этой командой:

```
wget -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NuGet/ServerCommon/$BuildBranch/build/init.ps1" -OutFile "$PSScriptRoot/build/init.ps1"
. "$PSScriptRoot/build/init.ps1" -BuildBranch "$BuildBranch"
```

Очевидно, чтобы они успешно скачались, надо передать скрипту переменную BuildBranch (файл build.cmd ее не передает).

PS Никогда не делайте так, как там сделано. Лучше уж сабмодули использовать чем оставлять в исходниках вот такую ссылку... Интересно, что они будут делать когда гитхаб в очередной раз сменит свои доменные имена?